# "git add *.js" did not add the files in sub-directories

Tags: git, github

Was trying to commit some changes. I used `git add` to add any new javascript files that I may have created using the wildcard `*.js`. Then I committed changes and pushed to github:

```
git add *.js
git commit -m "stuff"
git push github master
```

When I checked github, all the files that I had been editing were blank. They were there, just empty.

I then tried to commit again, but GIT said that everything was up to date.

Then I went back and noticed that after I did `git commit -m "stuff"`, GIT displayed a message saying that a bunch of my ".js" files were not staged even though I had just added them using the wildcard: `git add *.js`. This is the message that was displayed when I attempted to commit.

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   src/static/directory1/js/module1/file1.js
#       modified:   src/static/directory1/js/module1/file2.js
#       modified:   src/static/directory1/js/module2/file1.js
```

In order to fix this I had to go down a few directories when doing my `git add`:

```
git add src/static/directory1/*.js
```

This seemed to worked, because the files were there after I committed again and then pushed to github:

```
git commit -m "stuff"
git push github master
```

What was going on here, why did I have to navigate down a few directories to get the wild card to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative is to use the find command:

```
find . -name '*js' -exec git add {} \;
```

Running that without the exec will give you the list of files that you are working on; so, it is easy to tune this command to your liking.

Comment: This is actually the only thing that works on my machine, thanks so much!

Answer (score 35):

You need to use

```
git add '*.js'
```

You have to use quotes so git receives the wildcard before your shell does. If you do not have quotes the shell will only do the wildcard search within your current directory.

Comment: I can't seem to find any evidence that Git will recurse into subdirectories when given a wildcard (I tried it).

Comment: Ok, it seems to work there but not on my local machine. Was this perhaps a recent feature addition to Git?

Comment: Perhaps so. I just learned about it when that course came out in July 2012.

Comment: Curious. I tried with the latest Git 1.7.11.4 (on OS X) and could not replicate this recursive wildcard add behaviour.

Comment: try.github.com claims to be running 1.7.11.3, but it behaves differently from what I'm seeing.

Comment: Ok, I initially tried with a couple of files called `foo` in different directories and was using the wildcard `'f*'`. That did not work. When I renamed them both to `foo.txt` and used the wildcard `'*.txt'`, that worked. Using the original `foo` files with `'*o'` also worked. It appears that this recursive add support works only with the wildcard in the initial position.

Comment: @Greg git seems to match against the full path so if I have a file "a/b/c/foo.c" `git add 'a/b*'` will add it but not `git add 'foo*'`. At lest that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 16):

> even though I had just added them using the wildcard: `git add *.js`

Shell wildcard expansion does *not* recurse into subdirectories. The wildcard is expanded before Git gets a chance to see it.

If you use `git add '*.js'`, then Git will see the wildcard and will match it against all path names that end in `.js`. Because the `*` is in the initial position, this will end up recursively adding all `.js` files including in subdirectories.

Comment: Please don't steal my answer. :-) I am trying to get points on SO and you added my answer to yours 30 minutes after we had a discussion about my answer.

Comment: @AaronGray: not to worry, I upvoted your answer too, once I understood what was going on and why it worked.