# how to use regex in git checkout command to specify file subsets

Tags: regex, git

Say I am trying to checkout a certain set of git file, e.g. `app/*^(.tmpl).html`,

how to throw this regex into `git checkout branch -- (regex)`

Comment: What command did you use from my answer below? a `find --regex`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Is there a way to use wildcards with `git checkout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161521/6309)"

> Git does not deal with the wildcard, but your shell does.

As [noted below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931855/6309), you would need to escape the wildcard character in order for git to interpret it: `afile\*`, or use simple quotes.

The [example section of `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_examples) shows a wildcard usage:

```
rm hello.c
git checkout -- '*.c'
```

> **Note the quotes around `*.c`**.
> The file `hello.c` will also be checked out, even though it is no longer in the working tree, because the file globbing is used to match entries in the index (not in the working tree by the shell).

An alternative, for instance, would be to use find (as in "[“`git add *.js`” did not add the files in sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11980780/6309)")

```
find . -name '*js' -exec git checkout {} \;
```

You can try your regex with [`find -regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779844/6309)

For instance, [Tukaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518123/tukaz) uses (from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879041/how-to-use-regex-in-git-checkout-command-to-specify-file-subsets/24880000#comment125030136_24880000)):

> ```
> find ./packages/* -maxdepth 1 -name 'package.json' \
>      -exec git checkout {} \;
> ```
>
> in order to checkout only the `package.json` of each project I have and omit `dist` or `nodemodules` sub-folders.

---

The more modern command (since 2014) would be the [Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) (Q3 2019) [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore):

```
git restore -s=aBranch -- '*.c'
```

With '*.c' following the glob pattern described in [`pathspec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

Comment: maxdepth works fine ! thanks

Comment: @Tukaz Great! What was the full `find` command you have used, with `-maxdepth`?

Comment: find ./packages/* -maxdepth 1 -name 'package.json' -exec git checkout {} \;   

in order to checkout only the package.json of each project I have and omit dist or nodemodules sub folders for example

Comment: @Tukaz Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

Just updating this answer but I was able to `git checkout` with a wildcard so I believe this is possible now. I am running git version 1.9.3.

Comment: Note that the asterisk must be escaped, however: `git checkout foo\*`

Answer (score 2):

Git's [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) specials are poorly advertised, but they're quite capable:

```
git checkout ':!*.tmpl.*' app/\*.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using such combination of commands.

In case you need remote branch:

`git checkout $(git branch -a | grep "your-key-words-here" | grep remotes)`

And in case you need only local branch:

`git checkout $(git branch | grep "your-key-words-here")`

**Example of usage**

Mainly developers names branch by task number from JIRA or whatever, so using those commands you can faster switch to branch that you need.

***(1)*** All available local branches:

- feature/CAN2-1035_new_calculation_for_internal_transfer
- feature/CAN2-921_new_ui
- develop (current)

To switch on `feature/CAN2-1035_new_calculation_for_internal_transfer` branch, you should enter command:

`git checkout $(git branch | grep CAN2-1035)`

- `git branch` - will return all local branches ***(1)***
- `grep CAN2-1035` - will filter result of ***(1)*** and return only those that contains CAN2-1035

Those commands also could be extracted to some bash command to simplify usage.